# передача пропсов от ребенка к родителю

Tags: javascript, reactjs

уже долго не могу понять, как мне передать пропсы в реакт от ребенка к родителю. и сделать желательно без редакса

Comment: Передать пропсы от ребенка родителю, в явном виде нельзя, однако можно передать функцию, которая будет получать значения от ребенка. [Как передать данные в от ребенка родителю в react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454632/1454659#1454659)

Answer (score 0):

смотря, что именно вам надо передать, часто делают через события:

в родителе:

```
<>
    <Child onMyEvent = {this.onEventForParent}
</>
```

`onEvent` - это пропс для ребенка через который он будет дергать (когда надо) родительскую функцию и передавать через нее значения родителю

в ребенке:

```
this.props.onMyEvent(childData);
```

А уже внутри родительской `onEventForParent` вы можете изменить не родительские пропсы, но состояния