# Как обратиться к хуку подключенного компонента, находясь в классе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

В компоненте находится хук состояния:

```
const com = () => {
    const [payMethod, setPayM] = React.useState('');
    return(...);
}
```

Есть класс, в котором мне нужно получить значение payMethod:

```
class PayScreen extends Component<Props> {
    pay() {
        alert(payMethod);
    }
    render() {
        return(
           <com/>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Эти компоненты как то связаны между собой?

Comment: Связаны только тем, что в классе подключается компонент: import com from '../components/com';

Comment: Посмотрите тут, как [передать состояние из дочернего компонента в родительский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454632/1454659#1454659)

Comment: Это работает!!! Спасибо